# Automatic refresh

Tags: excel, vba, time, refresh, ontime

I have a problem with my file. In Visual Basic I have this code:

```
Sub Workbook_Open()
Application.OnTime TimeValue("01:00:00"), Procedure:="MyCode"
Application.OnTime TimeValue("02:00:00"), Procedure:="MyCode2"
Call MyCode2
End Sub
```

This code doesn't refresh my file at 01:00:00. This code doesn't "call" MyCode2. I don't have any bugs or errors. When I run my code manually, it works.

Comment: Do you have your computer running at 1am and 2am in the morning?  Was Excel also started and the file opened in this instance ? And is Excel in Ready mode? Please also have a look [here](https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/scheduling-macros-in-excel-with-application-ontime).

Comment: Okay, I know that excel won't run these procedures. But why can't he "Call MyCode2"?

Comment: Where is `MyCode2` located? In the same file in a module or in a class module of a sheet? Did you run a _Debug/Compile_? And if you do not have any bugs or erros then the code calls `Mycode2`! It is just not doing what you expect. You need to show the code of that sub `MyCode2` otherwise I can't really tell..